# log executed source code lines

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb

Is it possible with gdb (or other tools) to log every executed line of a program compiled with g++ -g? (i.e. log all source code lines that you would see when repeating the "step" command in gdb from program start to end)

Answer (score 0):

type
   **set logging on**
when you enter gdb.
and all output will be copy to gdb.txt
other commands are:
    **set logging of**  (disable log)
    **set logging file FILE** (change file name of log)
    **set logging overwrite** [on|off]
    **set logging redirect** [on|off]
    **show logging**

more information can be found in
[here](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/rtems/doc/html/gdb/gdb.info.Logging_output.html)